# AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'iget'

Tags: python

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt 
import shutil 

data = pd.read_excel('\\\desktop\data.xls', 
sheetname = '1', usecols = ['Date'] )

q_date = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'].iget(1)).strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
```

I get an error as below:
AttributeError: `'Series'` object has no attribute `'iget'`

Answer (score 2):

`iget` has been deprecated

Use `.iloc[i]` or `.iat[i]` instead
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.1/generated/pandas.Series.iget.html

Answer (score 0):

```
q_date = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'].iloc(1)).strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
```

or

```
q_date = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'].iat(1)).strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
```

`iget()` was deprecated a little while ago